# how to delete duplicate results of a join in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a join query as below :

```
$direction = $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
$data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'accommodation_rooms.accommodation_id')
    ->leftJoin('discounts', 'accommodation_rooms.id', '=', 'discounts.accommodation_room_id')
    ->select('accommodations.*', 'discounts.*')
    //            ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderBy('discounts.amount', 'desc');

return $data;
```

now this will bring me every hotel as much as their rooms so if a hotel has 20 rooms it brings back the same hotel 20 times and when i groupby i get

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in group statement is ambiguous

so how can I remove duplicate hotels and show only 1 for each room I also dont want to change the left join to join . please Advice. thanks

Comment: To solve ambiguity, just specify the table name before the column, like `->groupBy('table.name')` (not sure what table you want to use, and also not sure why you'd want to use `name` vs something more unique like `id`, but you get the idea)

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. You are mixing up the database layer (query results) with the presentation layer (how you want the results to look like in the web browser). Nothing prevents you from changing the join type, but the results will likely to be different. If not all the rooms have corresponding discounts, then you must use outer join.

Comment: @TimLewis group by without an aggregate function is pointless and the resulting query will probably be against the sql standard as well.

Comment: @Shadow Ah yeah, good call. It's possible there's an aggregate somewhere else in the code (`$query` is referenced but not defined in the current snippet), but you're right. That being said, my comment was mostly addressing how to handle the "ambiguous" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify what table a column is coming from in a Join query

```php
->groupBy('accommodation_rooms.name')
```

Or

```php
->groupBy('discounts.name')
```

And to get rid of duplicates, you should append a `distinct` statement

Comment: Group by without an aggregate function is pointless and the resulting query will probably be against the sql standard as well.

Comment: @Salim Djerbouch , what is the defference betwwen groupBy and distinct please ?